# Maven in Ubuntu 10.4 -

Tags: maven, ubuntu, maven-2, maven-plugin, ubuntu-10.04

This is my first time asking for help in a public forum. 
So anyways Microsoft Windows has been my comfort zone as a development environment,recently I have been chucked into a linux environment at work, I seem to have got the hang of things, but when I tried to set up Maven2 I ran into some issues, I will get to the issue part later, but this is how I set up maven

Extracted maven to `/usr/local/maven/apache-maven-2.2.1`

Created a symbolic link to '/usr/bin' using following command

`sudo ln -s /usr/local/maven/apache-maven-2.2.1 /usr/bin/mvn`

when I `mvn --version`

Output :

> Apache Maven 2.2.1 (r801777; 2009-08-07 00:46:01+0530) Java version:
>   1.7.0_25 Java home: /usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_25/jre Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8 OS name: "linux" version:
>   "2.6.32-24-generic" arch: "i386" Family: "unix"

but when I try to do

`mvn clean`

Output :

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Maven Default Project
[INFO]    task-segment: [clean]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.2/maven-clean-plugin-2.2.pom
[WARNING] Unable to get resource 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom:2.2' from repository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): Error transferring file: repo1.maven.org
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.2/maven-clean-plugin-2.2.pom
[WARNING] Unable to get resource 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom:2.2' from repository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): Error transferring file: repo1.maven.org

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Error building POM (may not be this project's POM).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maven is trying to download a plugin it needs to to do project cleanup from http://repo1.maven.org/.  Do you need to use a proxy to connect to the internet?  If so, see this guide:  http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html

If not,  it might be that the network somewhere between your workstation and repo1.maven.org was having problems, which might be resolved now.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by Ireeder(Thanks man :-) ) did the trick.

My computer was behind a proxy, so I needed to do the following to allow maven access the Internet

Steps to solve it

1. Open the M2_HOME/conf/settings.xml
2. Look for this line block in the settings.xml

   ```
   <proxy>
     <id>optional</id>
     <active>true</active>
     <protocol>http</protocol>
     <username>{username}</username>
     <password> {password} </password>
     <host>{host}</host>
     <port>{port}</port>
     <nonProxyHosts>local.net|some.host.com</nonProxyHosts>
   </proxy>
   ```
3. replace {value} with data relevant to you.

Enjoy!